# twain module: how to handle events python

Tags: python, python-2.7, event-handling, computer-vision, twain

I'm trying to get an image from a usb camera via a python (2.7) script on a windows 7 machine. The camera supports TWAIN so I'm using the pytwain package (version 1.0.5 at the moment).

The following code (example code from the documentation page of the twain module) works **only** if I type the commands one by one in IPython which has been started with the --gui=gtk option.

Code:

```
import twain
sm = twain.SourceManager(0)
sc = sm.OpenSource()
sc.RequestAcquire(0,0)
rv = sc.XferImageNatively()
(handle, count) = rv
twain.DIBToBMFile(handle, filename)
```

This code does not work if I place it in a script and run it, either with execfile() on a python console or %run on a IPython or "Run" from IDLE.

I think it is related to the way the events/messages from the twain functions (especially the RequestAcquire) are handled with/without a live gui environment.
I looked in the docs of the twain module and it seems that the RequestAcquire is not supposed to send messages or events...

Any help (either on twain or message/event handling) would be highly appreciated ;)

thanks!